# Windows 11 WSLg using integrated graphics. How can I get it to us my graphics card?

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11

I'm running RViz and Gazebo GUI applications from windows subsystem for linux(ubuntu 18.04) through the windows terminal. The applications launch fine and other less graphically intensive apps run fine. The two apps mentioned run incredibly slowly to the point they are unusable. Checking task manager the graphics card is not being used and only the integrated graphics is used. How can I get WSL to utilise both or at least force it to only use the graphics card.

Comment: [Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps) are the installation instrucitons

Comment: @Ramhound I've already installed WSL and can launch GUI applications. The trouble is they only use my integrated graphics which is unusably slow when using RViz/Gazebo

Comment: Did you install the AMD/Nvidia WSL drivers?

Comment: @Ramhound yes. Also I've already tried going to System>Display>Graphics and managed to add desktop window manager but that has had no impact. I've tried adding windows terminal here but can't locate the exe for it, even after going to task manager and right clicking windows terminal open file location.